# Intersection of two unsorted sets or lists

Tags: ds.algorithms

Suppose you are given two lists $L_1$ and $L_2$, each of which contains pairwise distinct elements from some set $S$.

**What is the complexity of computing the intersection $L_1\cap L_2$ of the two lists?**

If you have an order on $S$, you can sort your both lists and then compute the intersection in linear time, achieving $O(n\log n)$ complexity where $n=\max(|L_1|,|L_2|)$. More specific questions are then:

- Can you compute the intersection in linear time, or at least faster than $O(n\log n)$?
- If there is no natural order on $S$, what complexity can you achieve *without using a sorting algorithm*?

The second bullet point is quite vague. What I want to understand is whether sorting the lists (or one of them) is necessary though the answer does not need to be sorted.

Comment: Maybe you already know this but related topic is known as [element distinctness problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Element_distinctness_problem).

Comment: Related question http://stackoverflow.com/q/8102478/58737

Comment: This has an easy linear time hashing-based solution that strikes me more as being at an undergraduate homework level than research.

Comment: @DavidEppstein: I agree with you, I should have posted my question on cs.stackexchange. Yet, even though it was not precisely stated, I am interested in worst-case deterministic complexity. I doubt a hashing-based solution achieves linear time in these settings.

Comment: How do you represent the elements?  If they are bit strings that can have arbitrary length, then you likely can't have a worst case runtime even polynomial in *n* because a single string can be longer than $ \Omega(n) $.  If your elements have a bounded length, then you can sort in $ O(n) $ time.  If you mean something in between, what exactly?

Comment: @ZsbánAmbrus, We usually talk about integer RAM model, so your point I think is not concern here, see [this](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/1643/how-can-we-assume-that-basic-operations-on-numbers-take-constant-time). I'm agree with Bruno, that perhaps this is easy but I doubt that if it's that easy. I think some way around using r-lists can show that in comparison model this cannot be done in $o(n\log n)$, and hashbased solution has a bad worst case (hash is not that blackbox magic we expect in theory, but in practice is really a magic).

Comment: If one of your list has been already stored into a cuckoo hashing based hash-table, than you get worst-case linear time, owing to the fact that cuckoo hashing guarantees worst-case constant lookup time (but insertions require expected constant time; that is why I have asked if you allow neglecting the expected linear time required for building the hash-table initially).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the algebraic decision/computation tree models, your problem has an $\Omega(n\log n)$ lower bound, even if you know in advance that one of your lists contains the integers $1$ through $n$ in sorted order, and you only need to check whether the second list is a permutation of the first.

> **Proof (for algebraic computation trees):** The set of points whose coordinates are permutations of $(1,2,\dots,n)$ has $n!$ components. Ben-Or proved that for any algebraic computation tree of height $h$, the set of points in $R^n$ that reach YES leaves has at most $2^h 3^{n+h}$ components. Solve for $h$.

If you are restricted to equality tests, an $\Omega(n^2)$ lower bound follows from a straightforward adversary argument.